# com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate to java.util.Predicate

Tags: java, java-stream, querydsl

Is there any way to convert a QueryDSL Predicate to a java.util.Predicate.
It would be great if I could do something like this:

```
List<MyClass> values = ...
values.stream().filter(QMyClass.myClass.name.contains("test")).findAny().isPresent();
```

Comment: The case you are demontrating can be easily  converted to java predicate like this: `.filter(x -> x.getName().contains("test"))`. What's the point of using querydsl's predicate class?

Comment: That is a very simplyfied example. In truth there are predefined filters for nearly all my modelclasses. So I have something like `MyClassExpressions.nameContains("test")` which returns the Predicate you see above. There are several of these and some times I need to apply them to Lists rather than to SQL-Queries. I only asked because I wanted to avoid coding the same filters again in a diffrent way. It introduces an opportunity for making mistakes.